# Find command in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

If I have

```
i=find(10==[11 15 10 -7])
```

then i=3. But in the case

```
i=find(10==[11 15 11 -7])
```

then "ind=[](1x0)"

I neet to use the output of find command just when is a number, so I can't use

```
if find(10==[11 15 11 -7])==[]
   'this is not working'
end
```

How can I decide if the output is not "[](1x0)"?

Comment: Use `isempty(find(...))`.

Comment: perfect! Thanks @FabioSomenzi

Comment: This should have been in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope it can help you:

1) **`ismember()`**:

```
if ~ismember(10,[11,15,11,-7])
   'this is not working' 
end
```

2) **`sum(find())`**

```
if ~sum(find(10==[11,15,11,-7]))
   'this is not working'  
end
```

3) **`isempty(find())`**

```
if isempty(find(10==[11,15,11,-7])) 
   'this is not working' 
end
```